# Django ORM Annotate current company to users queryset

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have the following model:

```
class UserCompany(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Single user can have multiple `UserCompany` objects.

Now I want to query all users and annotate the queryset with `company_name`, `department`, `position` and `start_date` where the `end_date` is `null`. If there are more than one `UserCompany` object without `end_date` I don't care, any of them is fine.

I tried with raw sql subqueries like below and it seems to work, but I wonder if there is more efficient way to do this, or write this without raw sql. I know there is `Subquery` expression in Django 1.11+ but the version of Django I am using doesn't support it and I don't want to upgrade at this moment.

My solution:

```
from django.db.models.expressions import RawSQL


def create_rawSQL(field):
    return RawSQL(
        "SELECT `myapp_usercompany`.`%s` FROM `myapp_usercompany` WHERE `myapp_usercompany`.`user_id` = `auth_user`.`id` AND `myapp_usercompany`.`end_date` IS NULL LIMIT 1" % field, ()
    )

users = User.objects.all().annotate(
    company_name=create_rawSQL('company_name'),
    position=create_rawSQL('position'),
    department=create_rawSQL('department'),
    start_date=create_rawSQL('start_date')
)
```

I am using Django 1.9.8, Python 2.7.13 and MySQL. Thanks!

Comment: What do you intend to use those company related fields for?

Comment: For displaying user data in html table.

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to use your own User model and add the properties you want to it. This will probably be the most useful approach. The properties would look like something like this:

```
@property
def current_company(self):
    UserCompany.objects.filter(user=self, end_date=None).first()

@property
def company_name(self):
    self.current_company.name
```

Although I'd probably reference the company stuff through the current_company rather than adding the properties for most use cases.

If you really need the full annotated user set and there are a lot of them, I'd probably add a 'current_company' foreign key field to your user model and maintain it in the model methods. Then you can use normal django filters etc.